# Google Maps API v3 calculate distance ,duration Synchronously

Tags: javascript, ajax, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

Is there any way to calculate distance and duration in google maps v3 **synchronously**? I want to make a function which will take 2 parameter (latLng, latLng) and return the distance (not in straight line but through roads) between them (or the duration).

Comment: Doing this synchronously is not possible. Why do you require that this MUST be synchronous?

Answer (score 1):

You don't need Google. You need the [Haversine formula](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Haversine_formula):

```
R = earth’s radius (mean radius = 6,371km)
Δlat = lat2 − lat1
Δlong = long2 − long1
a = sin²(Δlat/2) + cos(lat1) * cos(lat2) * sin²(Δlong/2)
c = 2 * atan2(√a, √(1−a))
d = R * c
```

Comment: I know about haversine formula, but i don't want to calculate the distance in straight line, i want to caluculate it through roads.

Comment: Never mind, then. Maybe you'd want to add that *small* detail to your question?